# Ought brokerages clearly exhibit options' break-even prices?

Tags: discussion

Why did JTP unilaterally close [Ought brokerages clearly exhibit options' break-even prices?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/121234)?

This question involves the norm for break-even prices, not just Questrade. How can I know the norm, if I don't ask people at other brokerages?

#### Reply to JTP

What's the snag with "asking about 3rd party services"? Money SE has a [Questrade tag](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questrade)!

Answer (score 5):

Because ultimately, you are asking about 3rd party services. "Yes, my broker has that feature" then becomes a product/service recommendation. And, this type of question would otherwise become a survey, who has this feature, who does not.

Not a good fit for Money.SE. (And no, the math is not that complicated. But had I posted that to the question, it would appear unkind)